# Auto importing doesn't work with @emotion/styled

Tags: reactjs, vite, emotion, yarnpkg-v3

I practice yarn-berry with @emotion, vite, react.

But auto importing doesn't work with @emotion/styled.

[error image (doesn't auto-importing @emotion/styled)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pl0FL.png)

@emotion/react works well like this.

[success image (@emotion/react)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22fc9.png)

I did re-install after uninstall. but It doesn't solution.

what is the problem?

this is my dependencies in package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
```